# Python 3 - Extracting value from key in nested dictionary

Tags: json, dictionary, nested, python-3.8

Hoping for some pointers here as I'm striking out with my attempts. Am working with python 3.8.5.

I'm querying a Car Park booking system that returns a json list of availability. The result has lots of nested dictionaries and I'm struggling to extract just the values i want.

This is what I've been doing:

```
import requests
import json

enquiry = requests.post(url.....) #queries api, this works fine

results = enquiry.text #extracts response data

dictionary = json.loads(results) #convert response to python dict
```

If there is one slot available, I get this output (apologies for length). If there are multiple slots available, i get the same output repeated:

```
{
    "data": {
        "services": [{
            "id": null,
            "name": null,
            "services": [{
                "id": null,
                "name": "Car Park",
                "met": true,
                "filterCount": 1,
                "primary": true,
                "options": [{
                    "id": "9",
                    "images": [],
                    "available": true,
                    "calendarId": "AAAA",
                    "templateId": "BBBB",
                    "capacity": 0,
                    "name": "Car Park Slot 3",
                    "sessionId": "CCCC",
                    "functions": null,
                    "startDate": "2020-08-18T13:30:00Z", <--this is what I want to extract
                    "endDate": "2020-08-18T14:30:00Z",
                    "geo": {
                        "lat": 0.0,
                        "lng": 0.0
                    },
                    "selected": false,
                    "linkedServices": [],
                    "tiers": null
                }]
            }],
            "currentBookingId": null,
            "startDate": {
                "ms": 1597757400000,
                "year": 2020,
                "month": 8,
                "day": 18,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
                "time": {
                    "seconds": 0,
                    "minutes": 30,
                    "hours": 14,
                    "days": 0
                }
            },
            "endDate": {
                "ms": 1597761000000,
                "year": 2020,
                "month": 8,
                "day": 18,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
                "time": {
                    "seconds": 0,
                    "minutes": 30,
                    "hours": 15,
                    "days": 0
                }
            },
            "sessionId": "2222222",
            "chargeType": 1,
            "hasPrimaryBookable": false,
            "hasBookable": false,
            "hasDiscounts": false,
            "hasMultipleTiers": false,
            "isPreferred": false,
            "primaryServiceAvailable": true,
            "primaryServiceId": null,
            "primaryServiceType": "undefined",
            "unavailableAttendees": []
        }],
        "bookingLimit": null
    },
    "success": true,
    "suppress": false,
    "version": "2.3.293",
    "message": null,
    "result": null,
    "errors": null,
    "code": null,
    "flags": 0,
    "redirect": null
}
```

I want to extract:

```
"startDate": "2020-08-18T13:30:00Z"
```

from each key, value pair in any of the returned slots. However, I cant work it out.

Extracting the whole of this nested dictionary would also contain the same data, but would then involve more work to tidy it up after.

```
"startDate": {
                "ms": 1597757400000,
                "year": 2020,
                "month": 8,
                "day": 18,
                "dayOfWeek": 2,
                "time": {
                    "seconds": 0,
                    "minutes": 30,
                    "hours": 14,
                    "days": 0
                }
```

I've tried loads of dictionary.get and dictionary.items variations, but cant seem to get anywhere.

I tried something like

```
key = ('startDate')
availability = dictionary.get(key)
print(availability)
```

this just returns 'none', so think im way off

Any pointers?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the full data. It makes testing easier :)

I had to replace null -> None, true -> True, false -> False

```
slot = {
    "data": {
        "services": [{
            "id": None,
            "name": None,
            "services": [{
                "id": None,
                "name": "Car Park",
                "met": True,
                "filterCount": 1,
                "primary": True,
                "options": [{
                    "id": "9",
                    "images": [],
                    "available": True,
                    "calendarId": "AAAA",
                    "templateId": "BBBB",
                    "capacity": 0,
                    "name": "Car Park Slot 3",
                    "sessionId": "CCCC",
                    "functions": None,
                    "startDate": "2020-08-18T13:30:00Z", # <--this is what I want to extract
    ................
    
    
print("Start Date:", slot['data']['services'][0]['services'][0]['options'][0]['startDate'])
```

Output

```
Start Date: 2020-08-18T13:30:00Z
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! i think the null/none issue had caused a few of my other attempts to fail, i would never have thought to change that. Thanks again, much appreciated!